# MVC BeginCollectionItem Hidden index <li>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-lists, html-helper, begincollectionitem

I am using [BeginCollectionItem HTMLHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). It works as a charm but it messes up the layout I'm using. BeginCollectionItem renders a `<ul>` and `<li>` to hide it's hidden fields (which contains the unique indexes). So each 'row' you have in your collection will generate a `<li>`.

When you populate your table with BeginCollectionItem it generates the following above the `<table>`.

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

**The question:** I don't want those `<li>` and `<ul>` to be visible as the content of those are 'hidden fields' anyway. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: You could hide the `ul` (or `li`) elements with some CSS: `div#gridDiv ul { display: none; }`

Comment: That's one solution, but not a very clean one. I was hoping to not generate the elements at all. But thanks for the suggestion, didn't come up with that one yet.

Comment: I've not used that NuGet package, but is there a file called `Collection.cshtml` in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder in your project?

Comment: Yes there is. And yes, the `li` and `ul` elements are located there. I removed them and now it works as a charm. Thanks alot DavidG!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to edit the template file which is called `Collection.cshtml` and resides in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder in your project.

By default it looks like this:

```
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem

<ul>                                 
    @foreach (object item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem(Html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix))
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(_ => item, null, "")
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

So just edit it to suit your needs (perhaps simply removing the `ul` and `li` tags.